# requires unavailable feature android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer; failing

Tags: android, accelerometer

How can I resolve this error?

Android target is Android 2.2 Level 8

```
   -[2012-03-30 11:33:54 - GPS] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_FEATURE
   -[2012-03-30 11:33:54 - GPS] Please check logcat output for more details.
   -[2012-03-30 11:33:54 - GPS] Launch canceled!

03-30 09:21:05.114: E/PackageManager(59): Package com.lkv.mobile.apps.gcs requires unavailable feature android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer; failing!
```

The manifest file contain the uses-permission and uses-feature of accelerometer too.

Comment: Where are you trying to install the app? I mean device/emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your manifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"/>
```

Also try using higher version AVD or real device.

Comment: I changed to Android target version 4.03. I cant install to device I got a mess "Application Not Installed!" It does not work on emulator too. And set the minSdkVersion to 8 of course.

Comment: What is the version of Android you are running on your Device/Emulator? Does your device has Accelerometer hardware? changing  minSdkVersion has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The version is 2.2 on my device, minSdkVersion is 2.1  level7.
I tired with target version 2.1 and 2.2 and 4.03

Comment: Did you try after removing the above line?

Comment: I got an error message for next defined feature requires unavailable feature android.hardware.sensor.compass; failing!

Comment: make sure these features are available on your device. Are you able to download some app from Google Play which requires similar capabilities?

Comment: My device is a ZTE Blade which able to run application with this features. If I define the permission and use features for sensor accelerometer and set the target version to v2.1 or v2.2 it need to work, by my opinion. I hope I didn't miss out anything at all.

Comment: This problem still exists. :-(

Comment: I am not able to understand the cause of the problem. Please try on some other device first.

Comment: Other devices? If I removed the accelerometer feature usage and permission from manifest file, show exception again but with the next device which remain on manifest. I removed all devices what I used  in manifest, except for the Location. Show exception again missing feature Location. It's strange. The location exists in all devices. If I removed the MapView lib def from manifest and removed the usage from my code all works perfectly.

Comment: But still without MapView. :-(

Comment: I meant other device as some other phone. Also try creating a new project or things like that. Yours is not a real problem, just something is wrong and it's very difficult to find out what.

Comment: I found a solution for this problem, I removed all <uses-feature... from manifest file. It works perfectly! When I installed my app. shown correctly the used features. I don't know why does it works...